# how to display web view in android

Tags: android

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Is this a question? Please rephrase to include a question. It also doesn't help that we don't know what's inside MainActivity.java.

Comment: You can [Google](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&biw=1024&bih=656&q=Using+WebView+in+Android&aq=f&aqi=g2&aql=&oq=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=e0d5dd769eb87286) it.

Answer (score 2):

To start a browser:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.example.com");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

to start a WebView inside your Activity:

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
webview.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.org/");
```

It's all explained here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html